# Surprises are waiting to wow/woo you

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, word-choice, sentence-meaning

> Surprises are waiting to "**wow**" you.
>
> They **wowed** audiences on their play.

Mostly I have seen "**woo**" to describe how it has impressed/surprise someone.
"wow" in the both sentences mean the same?

Comment: *Woo* ((http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/woo) does not mean *surprise.*

Comment: Is it possible that you are you confusing the verb _woo_ with the [interjection _whoo_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whoo), as in, "Whoo-hoo! We won!" To _wow_ an audience would mean to impress them. To _woo_ an audience would be to try to entice them to come: _"The theater company wooed audiences to their play with free tickets and door prizes."_

Answer (score 1):

***If*** you are talking about *impressing* someone, it's *[wow](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=wowed)* and not *woo*.

The example there reads:

> The speaker *wowed* the audience

The audience got impressed by the speaker's speech.

Now, the verb *woo* which [means](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=woo) seek someone's favor or make advances towards

For instance,

> China is wooing Russia.

The past tense is *wooed*.

See the difference in pronunciations. Waav...and Woo